# How to implement regression/integration tests for a lambda function written in NodeJS in Terraform environment?

Tags: node.js, testing, aws-lambda, automated-tests

I have written unit tests for a AWS lambda function(using NodeJS) with Mocha and Chai libraries. I need to write integration tests as well (these tests will not use mock objects but make an actual call to the destination of the lambda function) as a part of CI/CD pipeline implementation. Does writing the same tests by removing the mock objects and making an actual call instead of a mock call count as integration/functional test? Is there a better way to implement the test, are there other libraries that I can use (something like Robot framework for example) to write the integration tests? We will use either Terraform with Harness to invoke these tests or CloudFormation. Can anyone suggest a better approach to writing these tests or Mocha with Chai is okay for integration tests?

Comment: Hi! Could you share please what you finally decided to use?

Comment: A not so elegant (I don't think it is, I may be wrong) solution was adopted. Just used Mocha and Chai without mocks/stubs.